# Displaying the submenu on the left side of page on clicking the horizontal main menu

Tags: model-view-controller, menu, submenu

In my Asp.net mvc application, I am trying to create a sub menu which displays on the left side of the page, while clicking the horizontal main menu on the top. I tried this link, but it does not help much: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16yk5dby.aspx. Can someone suggest an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating a user control for submenu . Call it with Html.RenderPartial on clicking the main menu.